# How can I interact with my deployed contract?

Tags: solidity, truffle, erc-20

What is the simplest way of interacting with a Deployed contract, considering that I am the owner of the contract (Token Contract).

I use Truffle/Solidity0.5.0/Open-Zeppelin/node10.15.0 nothing extra nothing else (web3 was installed during the deployment but no idea of how to use it)

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/token/0x975FB1824F82E446DD3F5c4cb04474468ED7d878

I mostly need to call functions mint() and burn().

Would appreciate if you can suggest me simplest ways of doing so.

Answer (score 1):

In your Truffle test, you can do something like:

```
const CONTRACT_ADDRESS = "0x975FB1824F82E446DD3F5c4cb04474468ED7d878";

contract("MyContractTest", function(accounts) {
    let myContract;

    before(async function() {
        myContract = await artifacts.require("MyContractName").at(CONTRACT_ADDRESS);
    });

    it("test", async function() {
        // Here, you can feel free to use myContract
    });
});
```

You can do something similar in your Truffle deployment script, just keep in mind that function `at` is an asynchronous function.